# Magento 2: Add extension attributes to product collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection, extension-attributes

I have added extension attribute to `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface` using `extension_attrributes.xml` and its getting reflected when I get product(s) using `ProductRepository`'s `get`, `getList` and `getById` methods.

Now I want to show those attributes data on product listing pages however, when I debugged that part, I have found out magento is using product collection to get products instead of product repository.

I know that we can use event observer (`catalog_product_collection_load_after`) to load external data but I want to know if there is any **optimal solution** for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Comment: @AnshuMishra Devdocs show how to add extension attributes to repos not collection...I think you missed that part from my question.